# Getting non unique elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is some lines of code I saw on Stackoverflow to find non-unique values in an array. I am not sure why it has to have 2 loops and the loop j is inside of loop i, can you guys help me explained

```
function removeUnique(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count >= 2) {
            newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(removeUnique([1, 2, 2, 4, 4]));
```

Comment: There are better ways of doing it

Comment: Yes, this is O(N^2), with using hashmap, you can achieve O(N). Basically you will the counts of each number in hashmap, go through hashmap and get the elements with the count of more than 1.

Answer (score 2):

if you check line by line it's easy to understand

```
function removeUnique(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
          console.log("loop i = "+arr[i]+" ,loop j = "+ arr[j])
            if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
               console.log("same")
              count++;
            }
        }
        if (count >= 2) {
            newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(removeUnique([1, 2, 2, 4, 4]));


output
    "loop i = 1 ,loop j = 1"
    > "same"
    > "loop i = 1 ,loop j = 2"
    > "loop i = 1 ,loop j = 2"
    > "loop i = 1 ,loop j = 4"
    > "loop i = 1 ,loop j = 4"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 1"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 2"
    > "same"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 2"
    > "same"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 4"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 4"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 1"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 2"
    > "same"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 2"
    > "same"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 4"
    > "loop i = 2 ,loop j = 4"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 1"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 2"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 2"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 4"
    > "same"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 4"
    > "same"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 1"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 2"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 2"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 4"
    > "same"
    > "loop i = 4 ,loop j = 4"
    > "same"
    > Array [2, 2, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is simple: for each element in the array, you have to count ocurrences of that element to know if it's unique or not.

The first loop (`i` loop) is responsible for the **"for each element in the array"** part, and the second loop (`j` loop) is resonsible for the **"count occurences of that element"** part.

**Note:**

The code as it stands is not ideal. To know if an element is not unique, you only need to know that that element occurs at least two times in the array. Also you can shorten this code by miles if you use `Array` functions such as [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf):

```
function removeUnique(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(number) {
        return arr.indexOf(number) !== arr.lastIndexOf(number);
    });
}
```

Which is shorter using arrow functions:

```
const removeUnique = arr => arr.filter(n => arr.indexOf(n) != arr.lastIndexOf(n));
```

The new function simply read: filter only elements from `arr` where the index of that element in the array (`indexOf`) is the different from the index of the element in the same array starting from the end (`lastIndexOf`).

Answer (score 1):

Think of it non programatically. For you to know that an element inside an array is non-unique, what would you do. You see an array and **see the first element** and **check** if its there in anywhere else in the rest of the array. And then you would repeat process for the second one and so on.

To achieve the same in a program, the process of **see the first element** is done in the outer loop and the process of **check** happens in the inner loop. Hence you need two loops.

Answer (score 0):

That's because, for each element, you need to check each element if it's the same as the current one.

Comment: do you mean that the 2 loops are looping through and comparing to each other at the same time?

Comment: Exactly, the first loop is picking an element to compare to the rest, and the second one actually compare the element with every other one. @Roselle